# Why didn't Harry deduce that Voldemort wasn't torturing Sirus because he would simply use the Imperius Curse?

Tags: harry-potter

In the *Order of the Phoenix*, Harry sees, inside his head, Voldemort torturing Sirius Black so that he would go fetch the prophecy.

From Harry’s perspective, that was real: Voldemort was indeed torturing Sirius, However, that made me wonder, why couldn’t Voldemort simply Imperius and control him? Furthermore, why did neither Harry nor Hermione (the smartest one) think of that? Being so smart, why didn’t Hermione deduce that if Voldemort were at the Ministry, he wouldn’t waste his time torturing Sirius and running the risk of getting caught, but actually controlling his mind?

Either there is a reason, which I don’t know, or it is a plot-hole (Or maybe Voldemort just wanted Sirius to fetch the prophecy ***aware*** of what he was doing, but that is quite stupid).

None of it happened though, but I’m discussing *Harry’s* perspective, he did think it was real.

Comment: Harry thought Voldemort was torturing Sirius Black, but, why wouldn't Voldemort simply control Sirius' mind to make him fetch the prophecy? And why didn't Harry realize that? I might have found a plothole.

Comment: To be honest, I just wanted people to think I didn't know what actually happened so that they would click on my question just to correct me, and then they would find out what I am talking about. Am I the first person to think of this?

Comment: While the answers are good, I suspect a good chunk of the reason is that Harry would have no reason *at all* to think Voldemort is ... rational, capable of using logic, prone to thinking things through?  Honestly, looking at how he has seen the guy act, I would expect Harry to easily believe he would be cruel for the sake of cruelty, or for some kind of maniacal showmanship, *even if* it cost him his plans (as it so often seemed to).

Comment: Besides the answers it's called 'emotion'. It's easy to abuse an emotional person and Harry is emotional. He's esp emotional when it concerns those he cares about. Not even close to a plot hole even without the fact an answer points out they knew Imperius wouldn't work for this (as it happened earlier in the book didn't it?).

Answer (score 5):

### First

Harry knows first hand that imperius can be fought off, specifically Voldemorts Imperus curse.

> ‘I asked you whether you want me to do that again?’ said
> Voldemort softly. ‘Answer me! Imperio!’
>
> And Harry felt, for the third time in his life, the sensation
> that his mind had been wiped of all thought ... ah, it was bliss,
> not to think, it was as though he was floating, dreaming ... just
> answer ‘no’ ... say ‘no’ ... just answer ‘no’ ...
>
> I will not, said a stronger voice, in the back of his head, I won’t
> answer ...
>
> Just answer ‘no’ ...
>
> I won’t do it, I won’t say it ...
>
> Just answer ‘no’ ...
>
> ‘I WON’T!’
>
> And these words burst from Harry’s mouth; they echoed through the
> graveyard, and the dream state was lifted as sud- denly as though cold
> water had been thrown over him – back rushed the aches that the
> Cruciatus curse had left all over his body – back rushed the
> realisation of where he was, and what he was facing ...

Sirius is Harrys idol, and the most strong willed person he knows, emphasized by the numerous times that year he disobeyed Dumbledore direct orders.

> ‘Harry, you’re to come with me and Tonks,’ shouted Mrs Weasley – over
> the repeated screeches of ‘MUDBLOODS! SCUM! CREATURES OF DIRT!’ –
> ‘Leave your trunk and your owl, Alastor’s going to deal with the
> luggage ... oh, for heaven’s sake, Sirius, Dumbledore said no!’
>
> A bear-like black dog had appeared at Harry’s side as he was clam-
> bering over the various trunks cluttering the hall to get to Mrs
> Weasley.
>
> ‘Oh honestly ...’ said Mrs Weasley despairingly. ‘Well, on your own
> head be it!’

### Second

Voldemort and Harry(+gang) already knew Imperius'd people were unable to retrieve the prophecy since Malfoy had already tried.

> “I was You-Know-Who,” said Harry, and he stretched out his hands in the darkness and held them up to his face to check that they were no longer deathly white and long-fingered. “He was with Rookwood, he’s one of the Death Eaters who escaped from Azkaban, remember? Rookwood’s just told him Bode couldn’t have done it . . .”
>
> “Done what?”
>
> “Remove something. . . . He said Bode would have known he couldn’t
> have done it. . . . Bode was under the Imperius Curse. . . . I think
> he said Malfoy’s dad put it on him . . .”

### Finally

Hermione tried to talk him out of it to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

### There are various reasons Voldemort might have used *Crucio*

There are at least two reasons Voldemort would conceivably not have used the Imperius Curse and (by extension) at least two reasons Harry and Hermione would not have been suspicious of Voldemort’s choice of the Cruciatus Curse in Harry’s vision.

- **The Imperius Curse is not foolproof.** Many strong-willed individuals can resist it, to one degree or another.

  > “Years back, there were a lot of witches and wizards being controlled
  >   by the Imperius Curse,” said Moody, and Harry knew he was talking
  >   about the days in which Voldemort had been all-powerful. “Some job for
  >   the Ministry, trying to sort out who was being forced to act, and who
  >   was acting of their own free will.
  >
  > “The Imperius Curse can be fought, and I’ll be teaching you how, but
  >   it takes real strength of character, and not everyone’s got it. Better
  >   avoid being hit with it if you can.”
  >
  > <sub>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*</sub>

  If anyone was strong-willed, it was Sirius. Harry and Hermione would have found it quite believable that the Imperius Curse would have no effect on him, and that Voldemort would have to resort to torture.
- The Trio had already speculated previously that **Voldemort had tried and failed to retrieve the “weapon” by casting the Imperius Curse** on Bode, an Unspeakable.

  > “I was You-Know-Who,” said Harry, and he stretched out his hands in
  >   the darkness and held them up to his face to check that they were no
  >   longer deathly white and long-fingered. “He was with Rookwood, he’s
  >   one of the Death Eaters who escaped from Azkaban, remember? Rookwood’s
  >   just told him Bode couldn’t have done it . . .”
  >
  > “Done what?”
  >
  > “Remove something. . . . He said Bode would have known he couldn’t
  >   have done it. . . . Bode was under the Imperius Curse. . . . I think
  >   he said Malfoy’s dad put it on him . . .”
  >
  > <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*</sub>

Together, these two reasons would have given Harry and Hermione little reason to be suspicious of Voldemort using the Imperius Curse.

### Any suspicions would have been dismissed

Besides, there were plenty of reasons to be suspicious of Harry’s vision, many of which were actually mentioned.

- Why would Voldemort think that Sirius could retrieve the weapon?

  > “But why,” Hermione persisted, “why on earth would Voldemort want to
  >   use Sirius to get the weapon, or whatever the thing is?”
  >
  > <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*</sub>
- How did he sneak into the Ministry?

  > “But . . . Harry, think about this,” said Hermione, taking a step
  >   toward him, “it’s five o’clock in the afternoon. . . . The Ministry of
  >   Magic must be full of workers. . . . How would Voldemort and Sirius
  >   have got in without being seen? Harry . . . they’re probably the two
  >   most wanted wizards in the world. . . . You think they could get into
  >   a building full of Aurors undetected?”
  >
  > <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*</sub>

After having seen Sirius being tortured with his own eyes (more or less), Harry dismissed even these substantive concerns, and Voldemort’s choice of interrogation method would have been low on the list.

What’s more, once Kreacher had shared his false information about Sirius’s whereabouts, **everyone would have been convinced regardless of their suspicions.** That was pretty strong confirmatory evidence, and no one would have suspected that Kreacher would mislead them.

Comment: Do you think it's worth adding that Voldemort, like many villains, makes mistakes based on his arrogance and pride despite his intelligence. It seems quite reasonable to me to think that he would torture someone like Sirius just to cause pain - both physically in Sirius and emotionally in those that cared about him. This I think would also help Harry to dismiss Hermione's logic-based doubts.